# Help using a few text boxes to display and save data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a db table like so:

```
Notes:
 -ID
 -Name
```

Then I have a product edit form that has 3 textboxes in which the user can save up to 3 different notes for a specific product. What is the best way to handle populating and then saving the data? If I use the code below to display it, how do I save it, as the textbox doesn't know the id of the note.

```
 var f = db.ItemsFeatures.Where(x=> x.ItemID == q.ItemID).Select(x => x);
        if (f.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                txtItem1.Text = f.First().Name.ToString();
                txt1 = f.First().FeatureID;

                txtItem2.Text = f.Skip(1).First().Name.ToString();
                txt2 = f.Skip(1).First().FeatureID;

                txtItem3.Text = f.Skip(2).First().Name.ToString();
                txt3 = f.Skip(2).First().FeatureID;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Would I use hidden fields? I have a feeling there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: I would say yes use a hidden field for the ID. It's confusing what your code is doing because you are getting a list of ItemFeatures and your schema is talking about notes. Are they equivalent?

Comment: @Matt, Yes they are same, sorry I used "Notes" in hopes of not confusing anyone. I call them features, but notes work too.

Comment: have you tested your above code? Does it actually display the right information. I would think the where clause could just be x => x.ItemID == someID where someID is passed to your function. Are you using a data access layer or are you accessing the linqtosql code from your codebehind page?

Comment: @Matt, Yes it display correctly, I'm using the data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own TextBox control inheriting from the existing TextBox control and populate the ID property as you have for the Text property.

When you retrieve the values remember if its during an event you may need to cast to your class not the base TextBox class.

```
public class MyTextBoxWithID : TextBox
{
    public int ID { get; set; }


}
```